# Round number of bits read to next byte

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I have a header that can be any number of bits, and there is a variable called ByteAlign that's calculated by subtracting the current file position from the file position at the beginning of the file, the point of this variable is to pad the header to the next complete byte. so if the header is taking up 57 bits, the ByteAlign variable needs to be 7 bits in length to pad the header to 64 bits total, or 8 bytes.

Solutions that don't work:

Variable % 8 - 8, the result is the answer, but negative.

8 % Variable; this is completely inaccurate, and gives answers like 29, which is blatantly wrong, the largest number it should be is 7.

how exactly do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
(8 - (Variable & 7)) & 7
```

Answer (score 4):

1. The number of bytes you need to accommodate `n` bits is `(n + 7) / 8`.
2. The number of bits in this is `8 * ((n + 7) / 8)`.
3. The amount of padding is thus `8 * ((n + 7) / 8) - n`.